# Conditional default export in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following JS code from a tutorial:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./configureStore.prod');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./configureStore.dev');
}
```

The `configureStore.*.ts` files both have a default export:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState?: State) {
    // ...
}
```

I want to translate the conditional export in the former code snippet into TypeScript. If I just leave the code as is, I get a compile-time error:

```
error TS2306: File 'configureStore.ts' is not a module.
```

After some trial and error I could get the following to compile:

```
import {Store} from "redux";
import {State} from "../reducers";

let configureStore: (state?: State) => Store<State>;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  configureStore = require("./configureStore.prod");
} else {
  configureStore = require("./configureStore.dev");
}

export default configureStore;
```

I tried using it like this:

```
import configureStore from "./store/configureStore";

const store = configureStore();
```

But I got this error message at runtime:

```
TypeError: configureStore_1.default is not a function
```

How can I successfully translate the original code into TypeScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  configureStore = require("./configureStore.prod").default;
} else {
  configureStore = require("./configureStore.dev").default;
}
```